# "(ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression" when trying to connect nodes when machine alias has hyphens

Tags: elixir

I'm going through a tutorial and am supposed to be connecting nodes together.  I'm starting up a total of four terminal windows using:

```
iex --sname one (two, three etc)
```

I then run

```
 Node.connect(:two@DAL-SW-JH-LT)
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression: :two@DAL - SW
    :erlang.-(:two@DAL, SW)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error says:

> ** (`ArithmeticError`) bad argument in arithmetic expression: `:two@DAL - SW`
> **`:erlang.-(:two@DAL, SW)`**

That said, [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) attempts to call subtraction operator there. The only suspicious subtraction operator we have is `-`, gluing parts of our node name.

Node names are denoted with *atoms*. According to the documentation, [`Atom`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/syntax-reference.html#atoms)...

> ...starts with a colon (`:`) which must be immediately followed by an underscore or a Unicode letter. The atom may continue using a sequence of Unicode letters, numbers, underscores, and `@`. Atoms may end in `!` or `?`. [...]
>
> If the colon is immediately followed by a pair of double- or single-quotes surrounding the atom name, the atom is considered quoted. In contrast with an unquoted atom, this one can be made of any Unicode character (not only letters), such as `:' Elixir'`, `:"++olá++"`, and `:"123"`.

That said, the solution would be *to quote* the atom, effectively surrounding it with quotes

```rb
Node.connect(:"two@DAL-SW-JH-LT")
```

Whether the node name has not contained dashes, quotes would be not necessary.